# Opacity of material in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, autodesk-forge

I'm using lambert shader and in the exaple it sets the material like this:

```
  this.material.uniforms.emissive.value = new THREE.Color(
  Math.random(),
  Math.random(),
  Math.random());
```

Before I had a simple shader that set the material like this where I could control the alpha:

```
this.material.uniforms.color.value = new THREE.Vector4(
  Math.random(),
  Math.random(),
  Math.random(),
  0.3)
```

But it looks like the lambert shader doesn't have a color vector4.

Any idea on how to control the alpha?

I use the same example for the lambert shader from here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-custom-shaders-part-2

And the simple shader was from: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2017/01/forge-viewer-custom-shaders-part-1.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you will have to use the [material](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/constants/Materials) opacity.
be sure to mark it as transparent first:

```
this.material.uniforms.transparent = true;
```

then set an opacity:

```
this.material.uniforms.opacity.value = 0.3;
```

if you already rendered the scene, you might have to mark it to update:

```
this.material.uniforms.needsUpdate = true;
```

for textures use .alphaMap

Comment: Any ideas why? ``

Comment: I think Philippe, the author of 2 blogs you mentioned before may have better answer. But just let you know, there is a known issue with Forge Viewer. The transparency of the different fragments will be taken into consideration while opening SVF file, this is in order to ensure that semi-transparent objects are rendered after the opaque ones. However, when changing the material of a fragment on-the-fly, the order is not updated because the viewer doesn't have a way to rebuild the BVHs on demand, and you can end up with something unexpected (opaque objects hidden by transparent objects)

Comment: Should be "this.material.uniforms.opacity.value = 0.3;"